# How to properly deal with rectangles being curved on geographies?

Tags: sql-server, spherical-geometry, geography-data-type, curved

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server to store simple data for administrative boundaries of the world (lots of polygons). I store this in a `geography` data type column. Afterwards I query these polygons by a bounding box and draw these polygons on the computer screen, using WebMercator projection.

But now I've noticed a problem. When I make a rectangle polygon in SQL server, it has curved edges. For example, the following query produces the following results (screenshot from SQL Server Management Studio):

```
select geography::Parse('POLYGON((10 50, 50 50, 50 60, 10 60, 10 50))')
union all
select geography::Parse('POLYGON((30 51, 24 48, 36 48, 30 51))')
```

[image]

Even more importantly - these two shapes are **NOT** considered to be overlapping by the `STIntersects()` function, even though they would intersect if the borders were straight.

In a sense this is actually **correct**. These are the shortest lines on a globe which connect the given points.

But this presents me with a problem - my viewport is a rectangle in WebMercator projection. I need to select all shapes which intersect with my viewport, and for that I need to get a truly rectangular rectangle to pass to the `STIntersects()` function.

And of course, I now realize that I'm probably drawing these polygons wrongly as well... or am I? I'm using the data from [Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/), although I'd like to switch to [OpenStreetMap](https://mapzen.com/data/borders/), since it has more useful data. But should the polygon data I acquire from these sources be drawn with the "curves enabled" or not?

I don't even know what this phenomenon is called, so I don't know what to Google for.

What is the correct manner of doing this?

Comment: Possibly use GEOMETRY type rather than GEOGRAPHY type or use a lot more vertices to have the geodesic lines follow the latitude/x lines more closely.

Comment: @mkennedy - I've considered using geometry, but that then gets problematic when my viewport is over the 180/-180 line.